# Conversion of UTC timestamp to epoch time in C

Tags: c, dst

I want to convert UTC timestamp in epoch time seconds considering DST in C language. I am doing development on VS 2005 as this is legacy product. I gone through various websites but it is not useful.

We can do this by boost library but it is not recommended.

I am passing input as "2017-03-12T01:00:00Z" i.e. UTC timestamp, and I want epoch time of it i.e. in seconds. When I convert this epoch time back to UTC time, it should give me exact result as input timestamp.

Comment: boost? in C? how?

Comment: @SouravGhosh The product mixed of C and C++.

Comment: That's fine, but I never known boost can be _used_ in C.

Comment: @SouravGhosh All it requires is cdecl wrapper function in C++ ,which can be called from C, and then uses boost.

Comment: @hyde Technically correct..but is it _worth_ it? Sorry if my statement was not clear earlier. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh For time and date related stuff specifically: If same library is used also from C++ part of the project, then I would say it is definitely worth it to use same library from C. Wether it is C or C++ library, doesn't matter, as long as it is the same library (or utility).

Comment: The POSIX answer is `strptime()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`mktime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime).

According to the man page, you have to parse the input and fill up the structure `tm`, defined as

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

and then, make a call to `mktime()` as

```
time_t result;
result = mktime(&t);
```

Point to note: Please read the linked manual and check for the applicable values of the structure members, especially

> `tm_mon`
>
> The number of months since January, in the range 0 to 11.

and

> `tm_year`
>
> The number of years since 1900.

Comment: When I convert the UTC timestamp into "tm" structure and passed it to mktime(), it result in epoch time but when I convert back epoch time to "tm" structure again using gmtime(), there is gap of 8 hours.

Comment: @Prashant Please show the code that is not working.

Comment: When I convert the UTC timestamp into "tm" structure and passed it to mktime(), it result in epoch time but when I convert back epoch time to "tm" structure again using gmtime(), there is gap of 8 hours.

Eg

tm localTMTest;
localTMTest.tm_year = 2017 - 1900;
localTMTest.tm_mon = 3 - 1;
localTMTest.tm_mday = 12;
localTMTest.tm_hour = 0;
localTMTest.tm_min = 0;
localTMTest.tm_sec = 0;
localTMTest.tm_isdst = -1;
time_t localTimeTest = mktime(&localTMTest);
struct tm *ptm = gmtime(&localTimeTest);

In ptm, hour is set to 8 because my timezone is set to "UTC-8 PST"

Comment: @Prashant I dont see that, check [this](https://onlinegdb.com/HyzIP-h6Q).

Comment: Thanks Sourav. But on my system it is showing 8 hours due to timezone in effect. When I run with IST timezone it is giving me date as 11 and time as 18:30 due to +05.30 time difference.

Comment: @Prashant If you already know the offset, just adjust it. However, `gmtime()` returns UTC - so not sure if the system timezone setting should affect that.

Comment: @SouravGhosh : [`mktime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime) interpretes the `struct tm` as local time, so that will depend on your system's timezone.